# Dynamic carousel codeigniter

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I am making an content management system. I can upload a new content for my website, but having problem displaying the images to my carousel. All images that I've uploaded, it goes vertically.

For example: I uploaded 3 images it will looke like this

```
Image 1
Image 2
Image 3
```

Expected output:

```
<- Image 1 -> <- Image 2 -> <- Image 3 ->
```

Question: How can I put all my upload images in to my carousel?

**View**

```php
<div class="container" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="max-width: 85.5%;">
     <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
       <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
       <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
       <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
       <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <?php foreach($content as $row):?>
        <div class="item active">
            <center><img src="<?= base_url().'assets/img/'.$row->content_image?>" width="100%" alt="Menu"></center>
        </div>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </div>
    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: All of your `item`s are `active`, only one of them should be.  My bet is your inline styling is messing things up - try getting rid of the `max-width`, and `width` on the image.

Comment: I also tried to remove the active, all my images is now gone.

Comment: You should not remove `active` completely. I said "only **one** of them should be".  If you remove them all, no image will be active, so none will show up as the first slide!

Comment: Sorry my bad, now how can I next/prev my carousel? its still now working.

Comment: I think you made a typo in your last comment so I'm not sure what you mean.  To be clear: 1) Is the original problem (vertical alignment vs normal horizontal carousel) solved? 2) What about next/prev?

Comment: It is now normal horizontal carousel but the < > to view all the images is not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158261/discussion-between-dont-panic-and-angel).

Comment: Hi sir, I sent you a message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php foreach($content as $row):?>
    <div class="item active">
    // ...
```

This means that every one of your carousel items has the `active` class.  [As the docs describe](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#carousel), only one of them should be active, and that's the one that will be displayed first.

Answer (score 1):

To make an dynamic carousel as @Dont Panic said, you only have to select one active for all of your items

```
<!-- Indicators --> 
<?php $count = 0; 
      $indicators = ''; 
         foreach ($content as $row): 
         $count++; 
           if ($count === 1) 
           { 
              $class = 'active'; 
           }  
           else 
           { 
              $class = ''; 
           }?> 

             <div class="item <?php echo $class; ?>"> 
                <center><img src="<?= base_url().'assets/img/'.$row->content_image?>" width="100%" alt="Menu"></center> 
             </div> 

             $indicators .= '<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="' . $count . '" class="' . $class . '"></li>';
             <?php endforeach;?>
```

And @Dont Panic made an dynamic indicator(indicator is the small circle) which is this.

```
 $indicators .= '<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="' . $count . '" class="' . $class . '"></li>' ;?><br>
```

I've encountered a minor issue, what if I only want to display all Active images/content and to my indicator?

In the code of @Don Panic it will still display all the images even though the other images are inactive.

Example:

```
I have  6 images,
4 images are active
2 images are inactive/deactivate
```

Scenario:

```
 In my indicator it displayed 6 even though the active are only 4.
```

So I improved his code into this

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <?php $count = 0; 
        $indicators = ''; 
        foreach ($content as $row): 
        $count++; 
        if ($count === 1) 
        { 
            $class = 'active'; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            $class = ''; 
        }?> 
        <?php  if($row->status == 'Active'):
            $indicators .= '<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="' . $count . '" class="' . $class . '"></li>' ;?><br> 
            <div class="item <?php echo $class; ?>"> 
                <center><img src="<?= base_url().'uploads/'.$row->content_image?>" width="100%" alt="Menu"></center> 
            </div>
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php endforeach;?> 
        <ol class="carousel-indicators"> 
            <?= $indicators; ?> 
        </ol>
    </div>
```

Now it only displayed 4 images and also the indicator.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxUxk.jpg)    The below code might help you if you have listed images on a page(or)view and now you want the image to popup and in the popup you need a carousel, as in the image i have uploaded.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxUxk.jpg)

```
note: that you have also fetched the no. of images i.e count by using num_row();
note: in header you have added these cdn

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"><!--BS CSS CDN-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><!--CDN FOR JQUERY-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script><!--CDN FOR AJAX-->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><!--BOOTSTRAP CDN-->


#model(gallery_m)



    //FUNCTION TO COUNT THE NO. OF ROWS/IMAGES IN A DATABASE
    public function count()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $q=$this->db->get('images');

        if($q)PART ELSE IT WILL JUMP TO THE ELSE PART
        {
            return $q->num_rows();ADMIN/GALLERY()
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


    //FUNCTION TO GET IMAGES FROM DATABASE
    public function gallery()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $q= $this->db->get('images');


        if($q->num_rows()>0)
        {
            return $q->result();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

#controller(Admin)



public function gallery()
    {
        $this->load->model('gallery_m');
        $data['images']= $this->gallery_m->gallery();
        $data['count']= $this->gallery_m->count();

        if($data['images'])
        {
            $this->load->view('gallery', $data);
        }
    }

#view(gallery)

          <!--begin modal window-->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg"><!--MODEL-LG IS USED FOR BIGGER MODEL-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <div class="pull-left">Gallery</div><!--HEADER TITLE-->
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" title="Close"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button><!--USING THE REMOVE MODEL ICON-->
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">

                        <!--CAROUSEL CODE GOES HERE-->
                        <!--begin carousel-->
                            <div id="myGallery" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                            <div class="carousel-inner">

                            <?php for($i=1; $i <= $count; $i++):?><!--USING FORLOOP TO MAKE THE FIRST ITEM ACTIVE WHEN CONDITION $==1 IS SATISFIED-->

                            <?php if($i==1) 
                            {
                            ?>
                                <div class="carousel-item active"><img src="<?= $image->image ?>" alt="images" style="height: 800px; width:916px">
                                </div>
                            <?php
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            ?>
                                <?php foreach($images as $image):?><!--USE OF SECOND FOREACH TO DISPLAY IMAGES THAT WE FERCHED FROM DATABASE-->
                                <div class="carousel-item"> <img src="<?= $image->image ?>" alt="images" style="height: 600px; width:916px">
                                </div>
                                <?php endforeach;?><!--END OF SECOND FOREACH LOOP-->
                            <?php
                            }
                            ?>

                            <?php endfor;?><!--END OF FORLOOP-->

                            <!--end carousel-inner--></div>
                                <!-- Left and right controls -->
                            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myGallery" data-slide="prev">
                                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myGallery" data-slide="next">
                                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
                            </a>
                            </div><!--end carousel-->
                        </div> <!--end modal-body-->
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <div class="pull-left">
                                </div>
                                <button class="btn-sm close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div><!--end modal-footer-->
                        </div><!--end modal-content-->
                </div><!--end modal-dialoge-->
            </div><!--end myModal-->



            <!-- Delete Button-->
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger remove" id="<?= $image->id?>"> Delete</button>


            <!--Update anchor-tag-->
            <?=anchor("admin/edit/{$image->id}", 'Edit', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']);?>
            <?php endforeach;?>
```